# Personalized Paging in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm doing a paging with an array in Laravel, and I don't know how to continue. It shows me the pagination links, it shows me only two array data when there are four, but the first page goes well then the next page redirects me to a route that does not exist.

Should I have any route on my web.php?

It is my controller:

```
 public function guardar(Request $request)
            {
                $marker = new Marker;
                $marker->name = $request->nombre;
                $marker->address = $request->direccion;

                $marker->idG = $request->idG;

                $pos = strpos($request->LatLng, ',');
                $latitud = substr($request->LatLng, 1, $pos-1);
                $longitud = substr($request->LatLng, $pos+1,strlen($request->LatLng));

                $marker->lat = $latitud;
                $marker->lng = $longitud;
                $marker->idMarker = $request->idMarker;
                $marker->type = $request->types;

                $marker->save();

                $busqueda = new Users_busquedas();
                $busqueda = $busqueda->ultimaBusquedaUser();

                $asesores = new Asesor();
                $asesores = $asesores->asesorByProvincia($busqueda->cbx_provincia);


                $datos = Array();
                foreach($asesores as $asesor){
                    //por cada asesor busco la provincia
                    $provincia = new Provincia;
                    $provincia = $provincia->getProvinciaAsesor($busqueda->cbx_provincia);
                    $municipio = new Municipio;
                    $municipio = $municipio->getMunicipioAsesor($asesor->cbx_municipio);

                    array_push($datos,$asesor->name,$asesor->email,$provincia[0]->provincia,$municipio[0]->municipio);
                // items per page
            $perPage = 8;

            $paginate = new Paginator($datos, $perPage);
            $paginate->withPath('guardar/next');
                }

                // var_dump($datos);
                return view('seleccionadoCCV',['marcas'=>$marker],['datos' => $paginate]);

            }
```

This is my view:

```
                    <?php
                    if (count($datos) == 0)
                    {
                        echo '<p><h2>Todavía no hay asesores en tu zona</h2></p>';
                    }
                    $count = 0;

                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($datos); $i++) {
                    $count++;
                    echo'<input type="text" class="nombre" readonly value="'. $datos[$i] .'">';
                        if($count%4 == 0)
                        {
                            echo'<input  class="bntSelectCC" type="button" value="Seleccionar">';
                            echo'<br>';
                        }                         
                    }
                    ?>

            </form>
            {{ $datos->links() }}

        </div>
```

When I give next it takes me to the next route and says it doesn't exist:

http://localhost:8000/guardar/next?page=2

I'm using Laravel version 6

Answer (score 0):

For Your Reference Please check My Sample Code Below:

Controller Code:

```
$usersListAry = DB::table('Users')->select('Users.*')->where('Users.isDeleted','=', 0)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(10);

return view('pages.adminUsers.user_list', compact('usersListAry'))->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 10);
```

View Pagination Code:

```
@if ($usersListAry->count()>0)
<div class="">
    {!! $usersListAry->render() !!}
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: I'm not using Eloquent. I need a method from paginate an array. And I am using version 6 of Laravel.